# Why doesn't prototype object change?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

As far as I know, objects are assigned by the reference (they are not copied). Therefore, if changes in an object occur via one link, then they occur via another.

```js
let a = {
  writer: 'J.K. Rowling',
  singer: 'Beyonce',
  politician: 'A. Merkel'
};

let b = a;
delete a.politician;

console.log(b); //there's no politicaian as well
```

Then... why do things work differently here? `prototype` is one object, so changes should be everywhere (by two links).

```js
let userInfo = {
    name: 'Kira',
    surname: 'Li',
    age: 25,
    country: 'USA',
    city: 'LA'
};

let food = {
    fruit: 'apple',
    vegetable: 'cabbage',
    pastry: 'bun',
    drink: 'water'
};

function Constructor() {};
Constructor.prototype = userInfo;
let obj = new Constructor;
Constructor.prototype = food; //reassignment

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); //userInfo
```

And here, for example, changes occur. Why?

```js
let userInfo = {
        name: 'Kira',
        surname: 'Li',
        age: 25,
        country: 'USA',
        city: 'LA'
    };

    let food = {
        fruit: 'apple',
        vegetable: 'cabbage',
        pastry: 'bun',
        drink: 'water'
    };

    function Constructor() {};
    Constructor.prototype = userInfo;
    let obj = new Constructor;
    Constructor.prototype.name = 'Klara'; //reassignment

    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
```

Why is that so? Why do changes happens in some cases and not in others?

Comment: `Constructor.prototype = food; //reassignment` reassignments don't propagate that to anything that uses that prototype. It *cannot*. `Constructor.prototype.name = 'Klara';` will *modify* the prototype and anything that uses it. Reassignments in general don't change all pointers to the original. `a = {foo: 1}; b = a; b = {bar: 2}` doesn't change `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples you are doing two different things:

- **Reassign** the prototype: will make **new objects** inherit from the new prototype, but **not previously created objects**. The old prototypes are being referenced directly by the old objects, so reassigning `Constructor.prototype` has no effect on them
- **Mutate** the prototype: changes the prototype of existing and future objects